# Python 3.* Assign value if variable receive an empty sequence

Tags: python

i have to search for certain patterns in a file that i have to open. If all the variables find the patterns, my code works fine, but if any pattern is not found, i receive the following error:

```
str2 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:TTTTTTCT)+', data))) // 8
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

what can i do to assign a default value to not receive this error in case one of the variables receive an empty sequence?

Sorry if i can't explain properly, english is not my native language and also i'm a beginner

these are my variables:

```
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

str1 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', data))) // 5

str2 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:TTTTTTCT)+', data))) // 8

str3 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:AATG)+', data))) // 4

str4 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:TCTAG)+', data))) // 5

str5 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:GATA)+', data))) // 4

str6 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:TATC)+', data))) // 4

str7 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:GAAA)+', data))) // 4

str8 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:TCTG)+', data))) // 4
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want your `max` call to be doing. Currently it will select the lexicographically maximal string matched by your regex but it's not clear that's actually what you want. If you want the *longest* string, you probably want to be calling `len` earlier, and you might be able to inject a zero more easily than you can with your current code.

Comment: @HeapOverflow actually str2 would be 2, but it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use what is called a [`Try...Except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) block.

What this will do is first *try* the code you want, and if it errors, perform an action. You could do it on `str1` for example, like so:

```
try:
    str1 = len(max(re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', data))) // 5
except:
    # This catches the specific error
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]

    # Set str1 to a default value
    str1 = "foo"

    # Print out the error for reference
    print("Received Error: {}".format(e))
```

[Also see this reference.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)

You could repeat this for each of your `str` variables

Comment: You almost never should use a bare `except` clause, some exceptions (like `KeyboardInterupt` generated by Ctrl+C, or `SystemExit` generated by calling `sys.exit`) should always be allowed to propagate. If you want to catch *most* exceptions (but not the ones I list above), catch the `Exception` type. That also lets you use `as e` to bind the exception object to a name, rather than needing to mess with `sys.exec_info`. And probably you only want to catch specific exceptions, like `ValueError` here.